# Why didn't JSON parser catch non-validated data?

Tags: ios, json, swift, error-handling, runtime-error

Once & awhile I get the **`fatal crash: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`**.

This can happen after a few iterations.

I've traced the source of the crash to (*what I believe it to be*)  the **`NSJSONSerialization`** parser that happens to get a non-validated string --> data.

That is, it works for a few iterations (exit, relaunch app & run again); then crashes.  Clear up the simulator & rebuild... pattern repeats.

I found this out by doing a **`println(string)`** just before the JSON call; and did a cut/paste of string into a JSON validator and found the ***errant* `'('` *at the beginning***:

```
({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":1340,.....
```

Here's the actual screen dump:

[image]

**Question:** why didn't the JSON parser trap this error within **`NSError`** vs throwing a **`fatal exception`**?  
...is this a bug?

Comment: I don't follow.  'jsonp' - json parser?

Comment: You sure the `(` isn't an indication that you're accidentally doing a `description` call on some iOS object?

Comment: And "Bad instruction" sounds to me like storage corruption.

Comment: I merely did a println(string) and did a copy/paste from the console to to an independent JSON validator app which noted the errant '('.  Once I removed the '(' it became validated.  I'm going to try to find the source of the'(' and/or clean the data up and try again.  Still, I shouldn't experience such a crash for corrupt JSON data.

Comment: As for 'storage corruption' -- any what to prove this, & remedy?  BTW: I've been testing for nils which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee JSONP stands for "JSON with padding

Comment: I traced the problem to an errant string-cleansing that occasionally leaves the '(' character at the beginning of the resultant string.  This appears to be random incident; so I have to recheck & rectify.  I don't know the cause; but it appears to solve the problem.  However, the JSON parser should have rejected the errant string with an error message rather than do a catastrophic crash. 

It appears we have a NSJSONSerialization bug.

Comment: If that's the case you should document it with a small testcase and submit a bug report.

Comment: This isn't throwing an exception, it's crashing. Your NSData may be getting released.

Answer (score 0):

You're forcibly unwrapping the object returned from `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()`, but it will be nil if a parser error occurs. When that happens, you crash with a runtime error.

Since you don't look at the contents of jsonError at all, you can ignore the error parameter and use optional binding instead; e.g.

```
if let JSONDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
  options: .AllowFragments,
  error: nil) as NSDictionary {
    // do something with JSONDict
} else {
    println("error")
    return
}
```

If you do want to inspect the error object, you could write it like this:

```
let JSONDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
  options: .AllowFragments,
  error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary?

if JSONDict == nil {
    if let err = jsonError {
        println(err.localizedDescription)
    }
    return
}

// Do something with JSONDict
```

Comment: Using '!' or not... same behavior.  Using '?' apparently only works with genuine Swift types; not with NSDictionary.  I'm using type NSDictionary vs 'Dictionary' and hence, get a compiler error for '?'.  And I need NSDictionary to work with NSJSONSerialization.  

Hence the dilemma: Need Cocoa/Obj-C API assets but compromise on the nil - safety/Options.